# How to define *args in a constructor function of a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started self learning Python and need some advise on the below problem which I'm working on currently.

1. How should I use the constructor method without knowing the total number of arguments to be passed.

How should I decorate each method of the calculator class, with a custom method that logs the arguements.(using a custom logger method)

Something like below:

`The Input Values are : '10' '21' and '15'` # if *args were 10, 21 & 15

```
Operation : Multiply
```

My unfinished code.

```
import logging


class Calculator:

    def add(self, *args):
        total = 0
        for val in args:
            total += int(val)
        return total

    def subtract(self, *args):
        total = 0
        for val in args:
            total -= val
        return total

    def multiply(self, *args):
        total = 1
        for val in args:
            total *= val
        return total

    def divide(self, *args):
        total = 1
        for val in args:
            total /= val
        return total
```

Below operations gives incorrect values:

```
print(Calculator.multiply(10, 2, 4))
print(Calculator.subtract(10, 2, 4))
print(Calculator.add(10,2,4))
print(Calculator.divide(10,2,4))

8
-6
6
0.125
```

Comment: Divide three number, what do you expect it to return ?

Comment: @Sushanth : I've edited my question. thanks for looking into this btw :)

Comment: Your `multiply` example gives 8 when you expect 80, right? I get, and expect, 80.

Comment: @jpf : Yes , I expect 80 but Ouput is 8..Not sure why 1st argument is not being considered. here 10.

Comment: Ah... nevermind. I instantiated `Calculator` before calling `multiply` from the instantiated object; you did not. If you call the method from the class itself, then your first argument (e.g. 10) is passed to `self` since there is no `self` of the object. Your class will function as expected if you first instantiate an object as `calc1=Calculator()`, then do, e.g., `print(calc1.multiply(10,2,4))` gives `80`.

Comment: @jf : I just corrected :)  how should I use constructor for this class and how can I use customer logger & decorator :) while Im trying from my end as well :)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post the expected results.

Comment: Concerning logging.

Normally the idea is, that your modules just call a logger, but do not configure the logger.

This should be done in the main function.

I will add the log functions to my answer. 

It would be good if you explain in more detail what you mean with *custom logger*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems.

The first problem is, that you create a class so you you have to instantiate an object before using it:

```
calculator = Calculator()
print(calculator.multiply(10, 2, 4))
print(calculator.subtract(10, 2, 4))
print(calculator.add(10,2,4))
print(calculator.divide(10,2,4))
```

if you type `Calculator.add(10,2,4))`
then the 10 will be passed as `self` and only `2` and `4` will be passed as `args`, so `args` would have been `[2, 4]` instead  of your expected `[10, 2, 4]`

The second problem is, that for `substract` and `divide` you have to treat the first parameter differently.

So following should work:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Calculator:

    def add(self, *args):
        logger.info("calc add %s", args)
        print("calc add ", args)
        total = 0
        for val in args:
            total += int(val)
        return total

    def subtract(self, *args):
        logger.info("calc subtract %s", args)
        print("calc substract ", args)
        if len(args) == 0:
            return 0
        total = args[0]
        for val in args[1:]:
            total -= val
        return total

    def multiply(self, *args):
        logger.info("calc multiply %s", args)
        print("calc multiply ", args)
        total = 1
        for val in args:
            total *= val
        return total

    def divide(self, *args):
        logger.info("calc divide %s", args)
        print("calc divide ", args)
        if len(args) == 0:
            return 1
        total = args[0]
        for val in args[1:]:
            total /= val
        return total


# Let's assume, that's the main function
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

calculator = Calculator()
print(calculator.multiply(10, 2, 4))
print(calculator.subtract(10, 2, 4))
print(calculator.add(10,2,4))
print(calculator.divide(10,2,4))
```

I added print statements for debugging. You had to remove them of course for 'production'

I configured the logging to write all logs with level DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR and critical for all modules into a log file.

To setup logging as you wish can be rather complex depending on your use case.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html is very complex and gives you a lot if freedom.
This is perhaps better treated in a separate question

**Addendum:**

Concerning the `__init__` function as you asked in one comment.

you might want to have a calculator, that remembers the last calculated

IN this case you would change your code slightly.

You would add an `__init__()` method

```
    def __init__(self):
        last_result = 0  # just some value
```

Then you had to change `multiply`, `subtract`, ... to store the last caclulated result.

e.g.

```
    def add(self, *args):
        logger.info("calc add %s", args)
        print("calc add ", args)
        total = 0
        for val in args:
            total += int(val)
        self.last_result = total  # no you remember the last result.
        return total
```

And if you wanted you could check now the last result. with
`print(calculator.last_result)`

What might really make sense for a calculator?

Perhaps the last `n` calculations (operation + parameters + result).

Perhaps a memory and a command to add or subtract the last result to that memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot  :) !! Actually Im going thru  the logging aspects of Python.. One more question here :)
How can I use __init__(constructor) method here ?

Comment: In fact your class is kind of a *strange* class. In python you use classes mostly for objects that have a *state* (that remember something). Your code remembers nothing.  If not you often use modules instead of classes.

Your calculator might for example remeber the last result or the last operation.
I'll enhance my answer to explain.

Comment: Great, thaks a lot for the explanation :)